# Keep feedback button to the right when horizontal scroll occurs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am developing feedback form in ASP.NET.   I am placing the feedback image on right by getting document.client width etc. (pleaes find complete code below)

Question:
I can maintain the position of feedback button when onresize event occurs

I want to maintain the feedack button and form to the right when user scrolls the page to right. How can I achieve this? Please refer to window.onScroll event below.

```
//JQUERY
$(document).ready(function() {
    var feed_width = $('#feedback').width();
    //var scr_w = window.innerwidth; // Screen Width
    var scr_w = (window.innerWidth ? window.innerWidth : (document.documentElement.clientWidth ? document.documentElement.clientWidth : document.body.offsetWidth));
    // 26 is width of the veritcal feedback button
    var btn_width = 26;
    var move_right = scr_w - btn_width - 15;
    var slide_from_right = scr_w - (feed_width - btn_width) - 26;
    var center = (scr_w / 2) - (feed_width / 2);
    var intX = document.getElementById('feedback').style.left;

    //maintain the spot when windows is resized
    window.onresize = function() {
        scr_w = (window.innerWidth ? window.innerWidth : (document.documentElement.clientWidth ? document.documentElement.clientWidth : document.body.offsetWidth));
        // 26 is width of the veritcal feedback button
        move_right = scr_w - btn_width;
        slide_from_right = scr_w - (feed_width - btn_width);
        positioningForm();
    }

    window.onscroll = function() {
        move_right = +move_right;
        positioningForm();
    }

    function positioningForm() {
        $('#feedback').css({ "left": move_right + "px" }).show();
        //ntX = document.getElementById('feedback').style.left;
        //document.getElementById('name').value = $('#hName').val();
    }

    function slideFromRight() {
        $('#feedback').animate(
    { left: slide_from_right + "px" },
    { duration: 'slow', easing: 'jswing' });

    }

    function moveRight() {
        $('#feedback').animate({ left: move_right + "px" }, { duration: 'slow', easing: 'jswing' });
        setTimeout("$('.right_btn').show();", 600);
    }

    // Positioning the feedback form at the time of page loading
    positioningForm();

    // Handling the right_btn and lift_btn event animations
    $('.right_btn').click(function() {
        slideFromRight();

    });

    // Moving left or right by clicking close button
    $('.feed_close').click(function() {
        moveRight();
    });

    //Submit button clicked
    $('#submit_btn').click(function() {
        var msg = $('#msg').val();
        if (msg.length > 0) {
            $('.right_btn').hide();
            $('.box').hide();
            $('#feedback').animate({ left: center + "px" }, { duration: 'slow', easing: 'jswing' });
            $('.thankyou').show();
        }
        else {
            $('#error').html('Enter some thing');
            $("#msg").focus();
        }
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
    body{
        width: 100%;
        overflow: auto;

        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        font-family:arial;
        white-space:nowrap;
    }

    h3
    { 
        color:black 
    }

    #feedback{
        width: 352px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 100px;
        display: none;

    }
    #feedback .formdiv{
        width: 300px;
        float: left;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 6px;
        -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 6px;

        min-height:100px;
        border:solid 1px black;
    }
    #feedback label{
        font:bold 11px arial;
        color: #80bae8;
    }
    #feedback textarea{
        width: 290px;
        height: 100px;
        color: black;
        font: normal 11px verdana;
        border: solid 1px #80bae8;
        padding: 5px;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        -moz-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px #4c0b3f;
        -webkit-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px #4c0b3f;
        resize: none;  /* disable extending textarea in chrome */
    }
    #feedback input[type="text"]{
        color: black;
        font: normal 11px verdana;
        padding: 3px;
        width: 200px;
        height: 25px;
        border: solid 1px #80bae8;
        color: black;
        -moz-border-radius: 4px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        -moz-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px #4c0b3f;
        -webkit-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px #4c0b3f;
    }
    #feedback input[type="submit"]{
        background-color: white;
        border: solid 1px #80bae8;
        color: #80bae8;
        font:bold 13px arial;
        padding: 2px 6px;
        -moz-border-radius: 8px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    #feedback .left_btn,
    #feedback .right_btn{
        width: 26px;
        height: 100px;
        float: left;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    #feedback .feed_close{
        cursor: pointer;
        margin:-10px -5px 0px 0px;

    }
    #error
    {
    color:red;
    padding:4px;
    font-size:11px;

    }
    .thankyou
    {
text-align:center;
display:none;


    }
    .textmsg
    {
    font-size:28px;
    font-family:'Georgia',Times New Roman,Times,serif;
    text-align:center;


    }

</style>
```

Comment: could not post HTML since it has image tag and as new user cant post it

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should be using CSS to position the button and form in a `fixed` position on screen.

For example, see how the `position:fixed`, `right` and `bottom` styles are used here:

```
<div style="width:2000px; background-color:yellow;">This is the thing that causing scrolling to the right.</div>

<div style="position:fixed; right:100px; bottom:100px; background-color:yellow;">
This is the thing that will stay fixed on screen.
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Oliver:Thank you for the repsonse.  The button should be displayed only and the form should be on the right side of the screen hidden from the user. When user clicks on the Feedback , the whole div swings in.